# how to check is certain time dimension persent in datetime column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

how can I check whether a particular section (ex: year or day) is present in the DateTime column in pandas? it's something like you want to examine the time gap between two rows in hours, but first, you need to check that the hour's section is present in DateTime.

desired outcome:

| datetime | is hours present |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-21 **17:24:00** | true |
| 2020-01-22 | false |
| 2020-01-23 **17:28:00** | true |
| 2020-01-24 | false |
| 2020-01-24 | false |

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I can't workout what you're asking, so hopefully this overkill helps;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# create dummy dataframe with mock data
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-01-02 00:00:00', '2021-01-03 00:00:00', '2021-01-04 00:00:00', '2021-01-05 00:00:00','2022-01-05 00:00:00']})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['day_of_week'] = df['datetime'].dt.day_name()
df['day_of_month'] = df['datetime'].dt.day
df['day_of_year'] = df['datetime'].dt.dayofyear
df['week_of_year'] = df['datetime'].dt.week
df['month_of_year'] = df['datetime'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['datetime'].dt.year
df['hour'] = df['datetime'].dt.hour
df['minute'] = df['datetime'].dt.minute
df['second'] = df['datetime'].dt.second

#check whether a particular section (ex: year or day) is present in the DateTime column in pandas
checkYear = df['datetime'].dt.year.isin([2021])

#show time gap between hours for each row and add new column to dataframe
df['time_gap'] = df['datetime'].diff().dt.total_seconds()

print(df)
print(checkYear)
```

Output:

```
    datetime day_of_week  day_of_month  day_of_year  week_of_year  month_of_year  year  hour  minute  second    time_gap
0 2021-01-01      Friday             1            1            53              1  2021     0       0       0         NaN
1 2021-01-02    Saturday             2            2            53              1  2021     0       0       0     86400.0
2 2021-01-03      Sunday             3            3            53              1  2021     0       0       0     86400.0
3 2021-01-04      Monday             4            4             1              1  2021     0       0       0     86400.0
4 2021-01-05     Tuesday             5            5             1              1  2021     0       0       0     86400.0
5 2022-01-05   Wednesday             5            5             1              1  2022     0       0       0  31536000.0
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
```